# Iterating over records of a model without knowing the model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Hi I try to create a gui for the all (ember-data) models used in my application.

Thats my router:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('config', function() {
      this.resource('configModel', {path: ':configModel'});
});
```

In config I want to list all defined Models. I do this by:

```
App.ConfigRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        var model = [];
        for(var property in App) {
            if(App[property] && App[property].superclass && App[property].superclass === DS.Model) {
                model.push({Name: property, Model: App[property].find()});
            }
        }
        controller.set('content', model);
    }
});
```

The config template looks like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        {{#each controller}}
            <li>{{#linkTo configModel Model}}{{Name}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    {{outlet}}
</div>
```

Up to here it works and I get a list of all models, which link me to the configModel route. In the configModel route I want to show a list of all records, but I don't know how to iterate over them. If the Model would be a list of user records I would do {{#each user in controller}}, but I don't know which model I'm working with, still I want a list of all its records.

Comment: can you show your `ConfigModelRoute` and `ConfigModelController`?

Comment: I didn't define them, because I thought I had nothing to define in them. The reason being that linkTo sends the correct model to the ConfigModelController. Should I had to implement logic in them?